# Swift / XMLParser / How to parse a specific element / CheatyXML

Tags: ios, swift

I want to parse and download the current EUR - USD exchange rate. I have descided to get the value from [the European Central Bank Feed](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml).

I'm using the [CheatyXML](https://github.com/lobodart/CheatyXML) XMLParser extension.

How can I get the USD value?

[image]

With the following code, I get the value: "European Central Bank". My String is an optional on porpuse. Because my app crashed like 1 trillion times during finding the correct code to get the currency rate...

```
    let feedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml")
    let parser: XMLParser! = XMLParser(contentsOfURL: feedUrl!)
    let exchangeString: String? = parser["gesmes:Sender"]["gesmes:name"].string // Returns an optional String
    print(exchangeString)
```

How do I get the value of `<Cube currency="USD"` ?

```
let blogName: String? = parser["Cube"]["Cube"].string // Returns an optional String
```

Is not working.
Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go one level deeper (there's three "Cube" fields), then get the attributes and finally subscript with the right key, for example:

```
parser["Cube"]["Cube"]["Cube"].attributes["currency"] as? String  // "USD"

parser["Cube"]["Cube"]["Cube"].attributes["rate"] as? String // "1.1287"
```